# Invalid Special character "Line Separator" LS is showing on mobile device chrome browsers

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, ansi

Please let me explain the scenario:

We have 1000 of physical html files having say news content which we dynamically list and show in our desktop and mobile site. 
The content is having "Live separator" character, So if i go and see the physical file its show some special character "LS" with black background. When i browse the page on my desktop device the special character is not showing but unfortunately this special character i.e. "LS" or   is showing a box with cross on my Android mobile with chrome browser.

The behavior is unique as for I Phone the special character is not showing the problem only exits for Android device + Chrome browser.

The special character description can be found in below link 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you found any way to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this symbol showing up on Chrome and not Firefox or Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603446/why-is-this-symbol-showing-up-on-chrome-and-not-firefox-or-edge)