# Strange LSEP Symbol Showing Up Randomly

Tags: html, wordpress, ascii

The U+2028 LSEP character keeps showing up around my wordpress site. Through the inspector, I can see that it is a locally rendered font such as Helvetica or Times New Roman (from what I've seen). It does not show up on all browsers however, I've seen some browsers not display this character.

[image: LSEP demo image]

I've found this [Why is this symbol showing up on Chrome and not Firefox or Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603446/why-is-this-symbol-showing-up-on-chrome-and-not-firefox-or-edge/39605739#39605739) however it hasn't really helped in removing the character from my site.

Is there a way to remove or disable the rendering of this character? While they dont show up on some computers, they still leave a blank space similar to a 
 tag, and it screws with the structure of the site.

Comment: The solution is probably to purge it from your data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884135/1264804.