# Deleting LSEP appearing on generated html pages

Tags: html, powershell, unicode

I am generating html pages from Edraw. But on those pages I have the `LSEP` character that appears just like that.

> EDIT : the problem seems to only appear on Chrome

[image: LSEP on my html]

So I know this is a common problem and I've seen a lot of forums about that issue but never a solution that suits me.

What I want to do is to find a way to delete all those `LSEP` in an automatic way (because I have 34 pages with this problem). Maybe write a script and I've tried some *powershell* but since I can't see or detect (thus copy it in my script) the `LSEP` in the code itself I can't delete it...

I saw [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736412/detecting-and-replacing-lsep-character-xb) that the problem came from a unicode, do I have to change the `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` balise ?

I also can't use http://www.nousphere.net/cleanspecial.php because my pages are too complicated so it messes up the whole code.

If anyone has a way to fix this thank you in advance ! Really !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for you here: [“L SEP” character shows up in Chrome](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/l-sep-character-shows-up-in-chrome/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&#8232;/g," ")); 
  });
});
```

Below a solution in Javascript you can put in the **head** section of the page. The '\u2028' is the unicode notation for character 8232

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   window.onload = function() { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u2028/g, ''); }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I use this ? I tried to put it in one of my webpage but it doesn't do much...

Comment: Wel, the example code was php. You could also add a piece of javascript in the head section of each page like: `<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
       window.onload = function() { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u2028/g, 'Y'); }
    //-->
    </script>`

Comment: Formatting a comment is terrible i'm afraid, so i wil update the answer to also inclkude the javascript bit..

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work, I don't really know why though... But I just found out it's only on chrome that LSEP shows up. So maybe I'll try to use another navigator until I find a solution

Comment: Maybe Chrome handles things differently and with the script in the `<head>` section, for Chrome the `<body>` is not even loaded ?
You could try and move the javascript to the bottom of the page, just above the final `</body>` tag. See if that does the trick.

Comment: Of course, if you move the script to the bottom of the page, you do no longer need the `window.onload` anymore since the page is loaded already there.  You can just do this: `<script type="text/javascript">
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u2028/g, ''); 
</script>`

Comment: Thanks ! It worked even though it deleted some elements of my page it does the job !